# PHP HTML - Sending uploaded files to Gmail

Tags: php, html, file, email, upload

Good day,

My objective is when customer upload his file(s), it will be sent to our Gmail, with the files attached. File should not be sent to our server as to prevent possible virus.

I also referenced [this website](https://www.codexworld.com/php-contact-form-send-email-with-attachment-on-submit) to understand how to send files to email. The website gets the file from the server after user upload, but we cannot do that. We need the files to send to Email directly.

I modified the code, But nothing happened when I upload file and click "Upload". I'm still learning html and php, and I hope someone can guide me on what's wrong with my code. Please be patient with me.

**This part of code grabs user's name and mobile from Database (Which I will need to forward to email)**

```
if(isset($valid_user_id) && !empty($valid_user_id))
{
$sql = "SELECT sno,emailid,fname,lname,mobile,address,city,state,country,status FROM member WHERE emailid='$valid_user_id'";
```

....
...
**This is the Form that ask user to upload documents**

```
<form method="post" name="uploadproof" id="uploadproof" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="wrap" name="wrap" value="upload" />
    <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value="<?php echo $valid_user_id; ?>" /> 
    
    <input type="file" id="images" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"/>   
    
    <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" class="send" value="Upload" style="float: none;padding:10px;" />
    <span id="load"></span>
    <br />
</form>
```

**This part of the code is the php that sends the attached files to Gmail**

```
$postData = $uploadedFile = $statusMsg = '';
$statusMsg = 'HELLO';
$msgClass = 'errordiv';
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $postData = $_POST;
    $email = $row[emailid];
    $name = $row[fname];
    $mobile = $row[mobile];
    $country = $row[country];

$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

        
        // Upload attachment file
        if(!empty($_FILES["images"]["name"])){
            
            //Get the uploaded file information
            $fileName = basename($_FILES["images"]["name"]);
            echo $fileName;
            //get the file extension of the file
            $fileType = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);
            
            //get file size
            $fileSize = $_FILES["images"]["size"]/1024; //size in KBs
            
            
            // Allow certain file formats
            $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                $uploadStatus = 1;
            }else{
                $uploadStatus = 0;
                $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, & PNG files are allowed to upload.';
            }
        }
        
        if($uploadStatus == 1){
            
            // Recipient
            $toEmail = 'Operation@gmail.com';

            // Sender
            $from = 'help@ecz.com';
            $fromName = 'ECZ Members KYC';
            
            // Subject
            $emailSubject = 'KYC Request Submitted by '.$name;
            
            // Message 
            $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                <p><b>Mobile:</b> '.$mobile.'</p>
                <p><b>Country:</b> '.$country.'</p>
                
                
                <p><b>Subject:</b> '.$subject.'</p>
                <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';
            
            // Header for sender info
            $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

            if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($fileName)){
                
                // Boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
                
                // Headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
                
                // Multipart boundary 
                $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 
                
                // Preparing attachment
                if(is_file($fileName)){
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    $fp =    @fopen($fileName,"rb");
                    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($fileName));
                    @fclose($fp);
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($fileName)."\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Description: ".basename($fileName)."\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($fileName)."\"; size=".filesize($fileName).";\n" . 
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                }
                
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                $returnpath = "-f" . $email;
                
                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
                
                // Delete attachment file from the server
                // @unlink($uploadedFile);
            }else{
                 // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";
                
                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers); 
            }
            
            // If mail sent
            if($mail){
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request has been submitted successfully !';
                $msgClass = 'succdiv';
                
                $postData = '';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request submission failed, please try again.';
            }
        }
    

}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: You can not send the file "directly", without it being sent to your server first. When the user submits the form, the file will be placed in a temporary directory on your server, and then your script needs to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Multipart email is a complex topic, you should really rather be using an established mailer library like PHPMailer, than try to implement this yourself.

Comment: @CBroe
Do you mean Pear Library like in this site?
https://html.form.guide/email-form/php-email-form-attachment/

Comment: Sure, if you like, you can use a PEAR package. I was talking about https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer though, that is more or less _the_ go-to solution when it comes to PHP, outside of frameworks that already come with their own mailer classes.

Comment: Why not just install a virus scanner on your server...

Comment: This code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  It also has some XSS issues.

Comment: @CBroe PHPMailer will require installation into the server?

Comment: PHPMailer is a library, you can either install it with Composer, or download the zip file which just contains a directory with a bunch of php files in it; that you then have to copy to your server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're (likely) going slightly the wrong way with this.

First of all, like `CBroe` already said, if you want to send e-mails, using PHPMailer will be a far better move than doing all this stuff manually.

But more so than that, i don't think you even need it.

---

Since you'd be sending these e-mails from your (web)server (PHP), the files are already on your server (that's how the magic `$_FILES` array works, it accepts the received files and stores them in one of your servers /tmp directories).

Protecting yourself or your users from being sent malicious files through this interface, will actually be rather easy (much easier than sending the e-mail).

Considering you're using `array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');` it's pretty clear that you only want to receive basic image files. JPEG and PNG images are more or less inherently safe (they don't contain any executable bits). So the only worry about be that someone is uploading another sort of file, renamed to look like a `.png/jpg`. (think `virus.exe.png`; or some other malicious content, renamed to `some.jpg`).

These cases are easily prevented.
When the form is submitted you can:

1. Verify that the extension of the original filename (`['name']`) is one of png|jpg|jpeg. You're already doing that (i would recommend adding a `strtolower($fileType)` to account for mixed-case variations).
2. Verify that the mimetype (`['type']`) is image/jpeg or image/png
3. Verify that the filesize is > 0 and <= your_max
4. Use PHP's `getimagesize()` to analyze the image, it'll return the (`[0] width`, `[1] height` and `[2] IMAGETYPE constant`) verify that the first 2 are `>0` and that the last one is either `IMAGETYPE_JPEG`|`IMAGETYPE_PNG`.
5. Now you can be sure you received a valid imagefile
6. (optionally) if you're really paranoid, you could create a fresh png image and use either the PHP `GD` or `ImageMagick` functions to import/overlay the submitted image over the fresh one, and then use that fresh file instead of the original. (i don't think there's a real reason though, but it would be a thorough way of avoiding things like hypothetical malicious EXIF data).
7. Now you can store the file with a generated filename (eg `<datetime>.png` or `<submissionid>_image1.png` or the like. or alternatively filter the original filename (`['name']`) with `preg_replace` to remove anything except basic word characters (say letters and numbers and underscore/dash). Either of those methods would prevent potentially malicious filenames.

---

I'd add that, if you still prefer an approach which uses e-mail, there are some other security concerns to think about.

Since these potentially malicious (submitted) files are e-mailed to your GMail address, you assume that Google will block these, or redirect them to your spambox, and you're probably right about that.

But that is only half the picture. Google will also realise it has been send a virus/malware/etc from the IP Address of **your** (mail)server, and likely with a `From: noreply@yourdomain.com` header in the e-mail. Now both your domain **and** your server ip address are going to suffer some reputational damage, which in turn will cause the regular e-mail that you and your collegues send, to increasingly often end up in the spambox of its intended target (whether they use gmail or not).